# Angular 5: Sending POST request with string parameters and FormData parameter together, to a Spring REST Controller

Tags: spring-boot, angular5, spring-restcontroller

I want to send a POST request from my service to a SpringBoot @RestController. I have a bunch of string parameters that I am sending, but I also have a FormData parameter which is an image (picture argument). If I do it like this:

```
  public createEvent(name, description, fromDate, toDate, userId, picture){
      this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'create',
          {
              name: name,
              description: description,
              fromYear: fromDate['year'],
              fromMonth: fromDate['month'],
              fromDay: fromDate['day'],
              toYear: toDate['year'],
              toMonth: toDate['month'],
              toDay: toDate['day'],
              userId: userId,
              picture: picture
          }).subscribe();
  }
```

And my Controller method looks like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/create")
    public void createEvent(@RequestBody Map map){}
```

The map looks like this:
[image]

and I can't get the file.
I can send the FormData as a single parameter in a post request and receive it as a Multipart file in my controller without any problems, but is it possible to send it in the same request with the other parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you can append all of the parameters in the FormData object, and access them through @RequestParam in the controller.